# selecting rows not in table created with mulitple join statements

Tags: sql

I have a schema like this:

```
create table AppUser (id int, name varchar(255));
insert into AppUser (id, name) values ('1','sashan');
insert into AppUser (id, name) values ('2','someone');
insert into AppUser (id, name) values ('3','mckenzie');
create table school (id int, name varchar(255));
insert into School (id, name) values ('1','pascoe high');
insert into School (id, name) values ('2','highbury');
insert into School (id, name) values ('3','hilton');
insert into School (id, name) values ('4','melbourne girls');
create table Student(SchoolId int, UserId int);
insert into Student (SchoolId, UserId) values ('2','1');
insert into Student (SchoolId, UserId) values ('3','1');
insert into Student (SchoolId, UserId) values ('4','3');
```

The AppUser table is the user info. The School table is the school info. The Student table links the school with the user. I want to select all schools that 'sashan' is not in.

I've come up with this:

```
select *
from School
left join Student
       on Student.SchoolId = School.Id
left join AppUser
       on AppUser.id = Student.userid
where AppUser.name is null
   or AppUser.name != 'sashan';
```

But want to know if there is a better way of doing it.

If you want to reproduce the table and test the sql using the code in this question see http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   School
WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT SchoolId
                  FROM   Student
                  JOIN   AppUser
                    ON   Student.UserId = AppUser.id
                   AND   name = 'sashan')
```

The query between brackets selects all school 'sashan' is in.
Selecting all schools not making part of these schools, you get those you requested.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select s.*
from School s 
where not exists (select 1
                  from Student st join
                       AppUser au
                       on au.id = st.userid
                  where st.SchoolId = s.Id and
                        au.name = 'sashan' 
                 );
```

Your version is not quite correct, because the condition on `'sashan'` needs to be in the `on` clause.  So the equivalent to the above is:

```
select s.*
from School s left join
     Student st
     on st.SchoolId = s.Id left join
     AppUser au
     on au.id = st.userid and au.name = 'sashan'
where au.name is null;
```

Comment: I think you meant au.name = 'sashan' in the first query. Otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: @sashang . . . Yes.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right. Here is an alternative version using `NOT EXISTS` cause

```
SELECT s.*
FROM school s
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 
   FROM student st 
   JOIN AppUser au ON au.name != 'sashan' AND au.id = st.userId 
   WHERE s.id = st.schoolId)
```

If you have right indexes then both the queries should work pretty well